# Custom rendering on FrontMatter markdown (to re-write img src)

Tags: reactjs, yaml-front-matter

With the Frontmatter [markdown compiler](https://hmsk.github.io/frontmatter-markdown-loader/react.html), it is possible to refer to completely custom components in the markdown, and then supply the component to render it in the `.tsx`

But what I am trying to do is render all `img` tags in a custom way.

Specifically, I just want to update the source, so `![](/assets/images/tux.png)` is rendered as `<img src="https://cdn.net/assets/images/tux.png" />`.  If anyone knows how to do that specifically, I’ll take it.

Right now, I am looping through the HTML nodes manually after rendering, finding the image tags, and updating the source, which besides being ugly hack, puts a 404 in the log, as the original, bad URL is fetched first.